# What I got is Modem-Router combo.How may I use the router functionality alone in this device?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I bought a Belkin N300 Modem Router combo.It has 1 phone line jack and 4 LAN jack.I already had another modem from my ISP. I used to connect the LAN cable coming out of that modem to my machine directly and use internet. Now I would like to have wireless internet available in my home everywhere. How can I set this up? Everywhere it is told to insert the LAN from modem to a jack named "Internet". I couldn't find any such jack I only have modem, numbered LAN and WLAN.

In a nutshell I have done a mistake by buying modem-router combo. How may I use the router functionality alone in this device?

Comment: Earlier using ISP modem I could c config page from http://192.168.1.1

Comment: Using Belkin modem I could c config page at 192.168.2.1

Comment: What is the make and model of the modem you have?

Comment: Belkin N300 Wireless N Modem -Router (model no : F9J1005v1)

Comment: I meant the modem you still plan to use.

Comment: That modem is provided by ISP, it is a real big outdoor modem I have a PoE cable running all the way from my room to the roof where the modem is kept. I opted for outdoor modem because of low signal strength in my area

Comment: If that modem has a built in router, you can follow my answer to use your wireless router as just an access point. If not, you'll need to get a router with an Ethernet Internet/WAN port.

Comment: I am very newbie in networking, It seems the ISP modem doesn't have a router. how may I confirm?

Comment: What are the first two octets of the IP address is assigned to your machine when you connect to the modem?

Comment: its starting like 192.168  and default gateway is 192.168.1.1

Comment: Then it sounds like there's a router built into your modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the router functionality of the device. You just need to use it as a wireless access point. Connect your modem to one of the N300's LAN ports. Make sure to disable the N300's DHCP server. (This assumes your ISP has provided you with a router, not just a modem.)

Comment: Would u please tel me what I need to do to make this work? Would u be kind enough to help me through team viewer?

Comment: Thanks David for all the help, It seems working fine now. I played around with all config values and I remember I changed the N300's ip address to point to ISP modem ip address and its working

Comment: It shouldn't matter what the N300's IP address is. You're just using it as an access point. Make sure you turn off the DHCP server in the N300.

Answer (score 0):

**Quick Answer:**
You can't. Modems are typically used to take an analog signal and convert it into a digital signal. Then it is sent to the router to be routed/switched. In your device this all happens in one device but your WAN cable will be for cable/DSL.

**Long Answer:**
Well, technically you might be able to but it would require a good deal of configuration. Since your ISP modem has an IP address it is a fairly safe assumption that it is in fact acting as a modem/router combo as well. If you turned your belkin combo into a dumb switch you might be able to do something with it. There is no guarantee that your router/modem combo would be capable of doing this.

*Tasks:*

1. DHCP forwarding would need to be set up on your Belkin to point at the ISP modem/router combo. Likely it is already doing it for your LAN and it is better to always just have 1 central DHCP server for a LAN. Much easier to manage
2. You need to configure one of the LAN ports as if it were a WAN port. All default routes should be pointed to the new WAN interface.
3. You can set up the WiFi but make sure the connection is bridged between the Wireless and the new WAN port you've created.